# Large matrix for surface plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm somewhat new to MATLAB and I'm trying to make a large matrix structured very much like the following example:

```
C=[1,2,3] 
n=[-3,0,3]
X=[f(1,-3),f(1,0),f(1,3);f(2,-3),f(2,0),f(2,3);f(3,-3),f(3,0),f(3,3)]
```

where `f` is some function of the values in `C` and `n`. I need this sort of matrix, `X`, so that I can make a surface graph of `surf(C,n,X)`. The issue is that, in my real problem, I need a 51x51 matrix, and I don't know how to make such a matrix without typing out everything (which would be a horrific task).

Could someone please help me understand how to make such a plot? Thank you so much!

Comment: Does `f` operate element-wise on array inputs as well as just a pair of scalars (e.g. `f(1,1)`) as you have shown?

Answer (score 0):

```
X = f(C'*ones(1, 51), ones(51, 1)*n))
```

Comment: I'm sorry; I can't seem to make this work. Could you please elaborate or provide a link that gives more insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
>> [ii,jj] = ndgrid(C,n)
ii =
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
jj =
    -3     0     3
    -3     0     3
    -3     0     3
```

Then you can get `X` very easily if `f` operates element-wise on non-scalar inputs:

```
X = f(ii,jj);
```

If `f` can only take a pair of scalars, try `arrayfun`:

```
X = arrayfun(@(x,y)f(x,y),ii,jj);
```

(Or modify `f`!)